# Executable using popen / pclose runs well as executable but fails as service

Tags: c, service, fork, popen

If I run a executable using popen()/pclose() runs well, but installed as a service it fails.

```
[Unit]
Description=Accessibility check
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/tmp
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/mx_qracc /etc/acc/mx_qracc_seraph.cnf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- including path in called executables
- including TYPE=forking in service unit
- increased timeout
- ...

```
int pingUrl(Text acHost, Text acCommand, int iCommandtimeout, pAccessibilitytype peAccessibility)
{
    int                 iRet = 0;
    Text                acTmp;
    Text                acReplacedcommand;
    FILE *              fileIn = NULL;
    Time                tWaitFor;

    ... 
            /** preset internal timeout */
            tWaitFor = time(NULL) + iCommandtimeout + 2;
            /** open query pipe */
            if ((fileIn = popen(acReplacedcommand, "re")) == NULL) {
                snprintf(acTmp, sText, "mx_cmdln.pingUrl.popen: %s:", strerror(errno));
                iRet = writeSyslog(eSlogError, acTmp, errno, 6);
                if (isTraceingenabled() == eTrue) {
                    snprintf(acTmp, sText, "mx_cmdln.pingUrl.popen: open pipe failed [command %s].", acReplacedcommand);
                    writeTracefile(acTmp);
                }
            }
            if (iRet == 0) {
                /** wait until command finished or internal timeout occurred */
                do {
                    /** check for output of query pipe */
                    if (fgets(acTmp, sText, fileIn) == NULL) {
                        sleep(1);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (acTmp[0] == '1') {
                            /** set accessibility state to online */
                            *peAccessibility = eAccess;
                        }
                        else if (acTmp[0] == '0') {
                            /** set accessibility state to offline */
                            *peAccessibility = eNoaccesstype;
                        }
                        else {
                            /** command failed */
                            snprintf(acTmp, sText, "mx_cmdln.pingUrl.fgets: [result length %d result %s].", strlen(acTmp), acTmp);
                            iRet = writeSyslog(eSlogError, acTmp, 7, 7);
                            /** set accessibility state to undefined */
                            *peAccessibility = eUnknownaccess;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } while (tWaitFor < time(NULL));
                /** close pipe */
                if ((iRet = pclose(fileIn)) == -1) {
                    snprintf(acTmp, sText, "mx_cmdln.pingUrl.pclose: %s:", strerror(errno));
                    iRet = writeSyslog(eSlogError, acTmp, errno, 8);
                }
            }
    ...
```

Error:

```
... seraph mx_qracc: SLOG_ERR    : mx_cmdln.pingUrl.pclose: No child processes: [code: 10 at pos: 8]
```

Inserted from comment:

```
acReplacedcommand: /bin/ping -c 1 -W 15 seraph | /bin/grep "1 packets transmitted" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: acReplacedcommand: /bin/ping -c 1 -W 15 seraph | /bin/grep "1 packets transmitted" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $4}'

Comment: If the command in your comment is relevant to the question you should add it to the question. You can edit your question to include missing information

Comment: I would have done if I could have saved the additional parts: 
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."